# Missing notification styles in Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-notifications

After I migrated my project to Android 8.0 (API 26), I receive this error:

```
error: resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification (aka com.xxx.yyy:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification) not found.
```

XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/notification_gap_text"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification" />
```

What should I do? Are there any new/substitute resources? My app's `minSdkVersion` is set to `15`. I can't use material resources which need minimum API 21.

Comment: Do you have the appcompat dependency?

Comment: @Zoe yes, absolutely. This: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using 6.0.0 version of stripe

Replace
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.1.0'
with
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the style was removed, but I extracted it from the `appcompat:25.1.1` and is defined as follow:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

You can define this style in your `styles.xml`